# C++ program running from C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local started by Registry CURRENT_USER

Tags: c++, windows, permissions, registry

I have a key in my registry that starts a program In my C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local folder when windows starts (Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) but when the program is started it does not seem to have write permissions to the folder it is in.

When I double click it to run it, it does have those permissions.

Does anyone know why it does not have permissions when started from the registry and if there is anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that current directory your process is running in is correct.
Use Process Explorer to check where your process is running.

Comment: Had this issue before and the working dir of the application was set to the desktop.